# Changing button text from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the face value of buttons using an array but what I've got doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var buttonValues = ["The letter 1", "The letter 2", "The letter 3", "The letter 4", "The letter 5"];
  var randomNumber = Math.floor((randomImages.length)*Math.random());
  $(".answer").text(buttonValues[randomNumber]);
});
```

JQuery above and the HTML below.

```
<button class="answer" id="1">a</button><br>
<button class="answer" id="2">b</button><br>
<button class="answer" id="3">c</button><br>
```

Any help would be appreciated, very new to jQuery. I have a couple of other functions going on in the JS file so will post a fiddle of the full code. I may have wrapped something wrong for all I now. Again very new to this. [fiddle of current progress](http://jsfiddle.net/r4emt/163/)

Thanks for the help everyone, realised the silly mistake I made with the code but got some extra advice as well.

Comment: what is `randomImages' ?

Comment: What is the final output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: randomImages is not defined`.

I think the variable `randomNumber` should be the length of the array `buttonValues`.

Than you should iterate over the buttons with class `.abswer` and set for [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) of them the [jQuery.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Note that inside of the `.each()` loop you should create the `randomNumber` in order to get different text for the `buttons` elements.

And finally, to get all buttons with a different text just remove from the array the element with the `randomNumber` created  index.

Code:

```js
var buttonValues = ['The letter 1', 'The letter 2', 'The letter 3', 'The letter 4', 'The letter 5'];

$('.answer').each(function() {
  var $button = $(this),
      randomNumber = Math.floor(buttonValues.length * Math.random());
  
  $button.text(buttonValues[randomNumber]);
  $button.attr('id', randomNumber);
  
  // Remove element with index randomNumber
  buttonValues.splice(randomNumber, 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="answers">
  <button class="answer" id="1">a</button><br>
  <button class="answer" id="2">b</button><br>
  <button class="answer" id="3">c</button><br>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a very helpful response. Is there any chance you could point me in the right direction for applying the random number so it edits the id tag too? It's fine if you don't want to, you have already helped me immensely.

Comment: You mean to set `id` attribute to `randomNumber + 1`

Comment: Yes this is what I'am after.

Comment: Updated the answer: `$button.attr('id', randomNumber);`

Answer (score 2):

You're using a variable which isn't defined:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((randomImages.length)*Math.random());
```

Should be:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((buttonValues.length)*Math.random());
```

I'm guessing you'll also want to set different text for each button. Your current approach will set the same text for every button in the collection. Something like this should work:

```
$('.answer').text(function() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor((buttonValues.length)*Math.random());
  return buttonValues[randomNumber];
});
```

**[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4emt/166/)**

Comment: That way you get different `button` elements with the same text.. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I too missed the variable name. Here is modified ans -

var buttonValues = ["The letter 1", "The letter 2", "The letter 3", "The letter 4", "The letter 5"];
var randomNumber = Math.floor((buttonValues.length)*Math.random());

`$(".answer").html(buttonValues[randomNumber]);`

Answer (score -2):

Your `randomImages` array is not defined, code to change button text itself (`$(".answer").text(...)`) is correct :)